# process.env returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I've imported dotenv using `require('dotenv').config();` at the top of the server.js file.
The .env file is in root folder

```js
require('dotenv').config();
//import dotenv from 'dotenv';
// import express from 'express';
// import viewEngine from '../config/viewEngine';
// import initWebRoute from './routes/web';
// import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
var express = require("express");
var viewEngine = require("./config/viewEngine");
var initWebRoute = require("./routes/web");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

let app = express();

// config view engine
viewEngine(app);

//use body-parser to post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// init all web routes
initWebRoute(app);

let port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, ()=>{
   console.log(`App is running at the port ${port}`) ;
});
```

process.env returns 'undefined'.
how can i fix this or is there an alternate way for importing environment file values

```js
PORT=8080
MY_VERIFY_FB_TOKEN=Randomstring
FB_PAGE_TOKEN=pagetoken
```

Comment: Can you post the .env file too?

Comment: @Erenn I just did

Comment: Remove the node_modules and do  npm install once.

Comment: When you say 'the .env file is in route', did you mean routes? If so you can supply an object to `config()` with custom path, example in the docs is like `require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })`

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth Already tried that. Tried it again although. Dosent help

Comment: @Brian path is specified if the .env file is anywhere else other than the root. Although  tried that as well

Comment: doesn't seems to have any issues. Can you try one codesandbox example with your setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED the issue. It lacked a .env.example file
.env.example works as a guide for creating a .env file with the needed informations that is needs to have the application running.

Comment: This isn't a good answer can you give more explanation behind what the fix does and how it applies to the OP's question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Used your snippets and it's working fine. Try running `npm i dotenv` again to make sure you have the module installed and updated.

btw, `body-parser` is deprecated. You can use `app.use(express.json());` instead.

Comment: snippets running fine, although the value are returning 'undefined'. Try running on gitcmd using 'node server.js'

Comment: I meant that `process.env.PORT` returns the correct value.